# Why *p++ dereferences a pointer first and then increments pointer adress?

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

The C operator precedence chart looks like this:
[image: C operator precedence]

Why is post increment/decrement first on the list but *p++ results in dereferencing a pointer first and then incrementing adress it points to?

Comment: Operator precedence is not the same as order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*p++` parses as `*(p++)`.

the value of `p++` is `p` (and the side effect is incrementing `p`), so the value of `*p++` is the same value as `*p`.

*Except for the side-effect, `*p` and `*p++` are identical.*

The exact same thing happens with integer:

```
int n = 6;
printf("%d\n", 7 * n);
printf("%d\n", 7 * n++); // except for the side-effect same value as above
```